# Proper using of IF in .check for dynamically extracting values

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I am trying to make .formParam- independent scenario with random values. So far I faced troubles trying to dynamically extract attributes from a request.

So firstly I need to check if the product is having any attributes (needed to be filled). Extract them by

```
regex("""\b(product_attribute_\d)(?![\s\S]*?\b\1)""").findAll.optional.saveAs("prod_attributes")   
prod_attributes -> List(product_attribute_1, product_attribute_2, product_attribute_3, product_attribute_4, product_attribute_5)
```

Then, if the attributes isn't empty (checkIf(!"prod_attributes".isEmpty)), I try to extract values for every attribute in Seq("prod_attributes"):

```
(for (i <- 0 to "${prod_attributes}".size - 1) {
  css("dd[id='product_attribute_input_" + i + 1 + "'][value]").findAll.saveAs("attribute_input_" + i + 1))
}
```

Now I want to create new Map and put as key = product_attribute_n, and value List of values for relevant attribute. For example:

```
val atrib_map= Map(
    product_attribute_1-> List(1, 2), 
    product_attribute_2-> List(3, 4, 5),
    ...... etc
)
```

**Or just extract random value for every attribute.**
And then use this list for .formParamSeq.

Please share your ideas about my approach, and help me find out if there any possibility to make it through. (Or I just dig in the wrong direction and it should be performed by simple "hardcoded" transactions)

This part doesn't work, but I'd like to use something like this.

```
val goToProduct = http("""Go_to_product""")
    .get("/product")
    .headers(headers_0)
    .check(
     regex("""\b(product_attribute_\d)(?![\s\S]*\b\1)""").findAll.optional.saveAs("prod_attributes"),
     checkIf(!"prod_attributes".isEmpty){
      for (i <- 0 to "${prod_attributes}".size - 1) {
        css("dd[id='product_attribute_input_" + i + 1 + "'] [value]").findAll.saveAs("attribute_input_" + i + 1)
        }
    })
```

I have this part of body (this is item with most attributes to be filled).

Main idea to have not hardcoded values, that can be parsed from any product ( with 2,3,4, any attributes).

```html
 <!--attributes-->
    <div class="attributes">
        <dl>
            <dt id="product_attribute_label_1">
            <label class="text-prompt">
            Processor
            </label>
            <span class="required">*</span>
            </dt>
            <dd id="product_attribute_input_1">
               <select name="product_attribute_1" id="product_attribute_1">
                    <option value="1">2.2 GHz Intel Pentium Dual-Core E2200</option>
                    <option selected="selected" value="2">2.5 GHz Intel Pentium Dual-Core E2200 [+$15.00]</option>
               </select>
                                
            </dd>
            <dt id="product_attribute_label_2">
                <label class="text-prompt">
                    RAM
                </label>
                <span class="required">*</span>
            </dt>
                <dd id="product_attribute_input_2">
                    <select name="product_attribute_2" id="product_attribute_2">
                        <option value="3">2 GB</option>
                        <option value="4">4GB [+$20.00]</option>
                        <option value="5">8GB [+$60.00]</option>
                    </select>
                                
                </dd>
                <dt id="product_attribute_label_3">
                    <label class="text-prompt">
                        HDD
                    </label>
                        <span class="required">*</span>
                                    </dt>
                <dd id="product_attribute_input_3">
                    <ul class="option-list">
                        <li>
                            <input id="product_attribute_3_6" type="radio" name="product_attribute_3" value="6">
                            <label for="product_attribute_3_6">320 GB</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input id="product_attribute_3_7" type="radio" name="product_attribute_3" value="7">
                            <label for="product_attribute_3_7">400 GB [+$100.00]</label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                                
                </dd>
                <dt id="product_attribute_label_4">
                    <label class="text-prompt">
                        OS
                    </label>
                        <span class="required">*</span>
                    </dt>
                <dd id="product_attribute_input_4">
                     <ul class="option-list">
                         <li>
                            <input id="product_attribute_4_8" type="radio" name="product_attribute_4" value="8" checked="checked">
                            <label for="product_attribute_4_8">Vista Home [+$50.00]</label>

                         </li>
                         <li>
                            <input id="product_attribute_4_9" type="radio" name="product_attribute_4" value="9">
                            <label for="product_attribute_4_9">Vista Premium [+$60.00]</label>
                         </li>
                     </ul>
                                
                </dd>
                <dt id="product_attribute_label_5">
                    <label class="text-prompt">
                        Software
                    </label>
                </dt>
                <dd id="product_attribute_input_5">
                     <ul class="option-list">
                        <li>
                            <input id="product_attribute_5_10" type="checkbox" name="product_attribute_5" value="10" checked="checked">
                            <label for="product_attribute_5_10">Microsoft Office [+$50.00]</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input id="product_attribute_5_11" type="checkbox" name="product_attribute_5" value="11">
                            <label for="product_attribute_5_11">Acrobat Reader [+$10.00]</label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input id="product_attribute_5_12" type="checkbox" name="product_attribute_5" value="12">
                            <label for="product_attribute_5_12">Total Commander [+$5.00]</label>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                </dd>
        </dl>
        
    </div>
```

Comment: can you share an example of the response payloads you get and a desired subsequent request?

Comment: Yes. I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not seem that you can dynamically add checks.

My solution gets the nodes and `transform`s them. Note the `^=` which selects all the nodes starting with "product_attribute_input_".

```
.check(
  css("""dd[id^="product_attribute_input_"]""").ofType[jodd.lagarto.dom.Node].findAll
  .transform{ nodes => 
    nodes.map { node =>
      val name = node.getAttribute("id")
      val valuesInSelect = Option(node.getFirstChildElement("select")).map {
        _.getChildElements().flatMap {  child =>
          Option(child.getAttribute("value"))
        }
        .toList
      }
      val valuesInList = Option(node.getFirstChildElement("ul")).map {
        _.getChildElements()
          .filter { _.getNodeName() == "li" }
          .flatMap { child =>
            Option(child.getFirstChildElement("input")).flatMap { i =>
              Option(i.getAttribute("value"))
            }
          }
          .toList
      }
      name -> valuesInSelect.orElse(valuesInList).getOrElse(List())
    }.toMap
  }
  .saveAs("atrib_map")
)
```

When you print the session, you can see the attribute to be `atrib_map -> Map(product_attribute_input_3 -> List(6, 7), product_attribute_input_5 -> List(10, 11, 12), product_attribute_input_2 -> List(3, 4, 5), product_attribute_input_4 -> List(8, 9), product_attribute_input_1 -> List(1, 2))`

---

This extraction of data from an XML node is not really efficient or elegant, but it feels declarative.

Comment: I think your approach is best for my purpose. I didn't clearly explain my problem. But in your example I found the answer)

Comment: There's one more question. Am I able to extract values not only from Option(node.getFirstChildElement("select")) in one check? Some of the field isn't "select", but <li>. Maybe some thing like node.getChilds with different names and take "value" attribute ?

Comment: In some sense, this solution “escapes” from the Gatling DSL into Scala, a general-purpose language. You get to do whatever you want, if you know Scala.

Comment: I will update my answer to include the missed cases when I have my computer with me.

Comment: Sorry to bother you , but could you explain why this bit of code doesn't work properly? I am trying to parse all the child nodes of the current `product_attribute_input_n` but instead of getting list of results `List(val1,val2,..)` I have got empty list. `transform { nodes => nodes.map { node => val name = node.getAttribute("id") val values = Option(node.getChildNodes.flatMap { ch => Option(ch.getAttribute("value")) }.toList) name -> values.getOrElse(List()) }.toMap } .saveAs("atrib_map")`

Comment: `node.getChildNodes.filter(_.getAttribute("value")!= "").flatMap(_.getAttribute("value")).toList` also doesn't work

Comment: @NickolayAveryanov, because the nodes with `value` are the **grand**children, or _great_**grand**children of the nodes. You looked for child nodes, only one layer deep.

Comment: one more question please) If I have more than 2 items for the map `name -> valuesInSelect.orElse(valuesInList).getOrElse(List())` I tried to add one more `.orElse after .orElse(valuesInList)` but last bit was always empty. `valuesInSelect.orElse(valuesInList).orElse(willBeEmpty).getOrElse(List())`

Comment: so I came up and combine 2 items for getting values `val valuesInList = Option(node.getFirstChildElement("ul")).map { _.getChildElements().filter {_.getNodeName() == "li"}.flatMap { child =>{Option(child.getFirstChildElement("input")).flatMap { i =>Option(i.getAttribute("value"))}}.orElse{Option(child.getFirstChildElement("label")).flatMap { i =>Option(i.getFirstChildElement("input")).flatMap { e =>Option(e.getAttribute("value"))}
                    }}}.toList}
            name -> valuesInSelect.orElse(valuesInList).getOrElse(List())` Is this appropriate solving??

Comment: `orElse` ignores the argument when the first is not empty. If you want to combine two lists the operator to use is `++`.